# Data.table ":=" assignment gives "incorrect number of dimensions" error with mtcars but not other sample data

Tags: r, data.table

**UPDATE:** I've discovered this is an odd quirk. If working with Foo from as.data.table(Foo) data.table's functions will work fine, but if you copy Foo as in Bar<-Foo then data.table's functions will throw an error when used on Bar.

---

I'm trying to learn the use of the data.table package because I'm about to start a project that will do a *lot* of editing cells and copying rows back and forth between multiple extremely large (>100K-1M rows) tables and from what I understand data.table vastly outperforms everything else in these use cases.

To practice I used this code to replace the 2nd row of column Y with the data from the 5th row of column Y, and it worked just fine:

```
DT <- data.table(x = 1:5, y = 6:10, z = 11:15)
DT[2, y := DT[5, y]]
```

On the other hand doing the *exact same thing* with a copy of mtcars converted va as.data.table throws an error no matter which column I try to do this in (for clarification "m" is simply the name of the first column automatically assigned by as.data.table()):

```
mtcarstable<-as.data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = TRUE)
mtcarstable[2, m := mtcarstable[3, m]]
Error in mtcarstable[3, m] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

The only other references I found to the "incorrect number of dimensions" error didn't appear to have anything to do with this situation.

Comment: in your qn, what is m? if its a character vector of column names, you might be looking for `mtcarstable[2, (m) := mtcarstable[3, m]]`

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, except for the problem that 'm' is not a column in mtcars. For instance `mtcarstable[2, wt := mtcarstable[3, wt]]` seems to work fine.

Comment: "m" was just the name automatically assigned by as.data.table when I set it to keep row names, but I actually think I just figured out the issue... and opened a new one. Working with a data.table converted directly by as.data.table() works perfectly fine, but if you copy that data.table (IE Foo<-Bar) then Foo will throw an error while Bar will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the breakdown. When posting this question I pasted in my code with the original as.data.table() converted mtcars copy. However what I was actually working with was a second-order copy, IE:

```
mtcarstable<-as.data.table(mtcars, keep.rownames = TRUE)
mtcars2<-mtcarstable
mtcars2[2, cyl := mtcars2[3, cyl]]
```

For some reason this works fine:

```
mtcarstable[2, wt := mtcarstable[3, wt]]
```

while on the other hand the perfect copy of it does not

```
mtcars2<-mtcarstable
mtcars2[2, wt := mtcars2[3, wt]]
Error in mtcars2[3, wt] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: why is the error saying `cyl` instead of `wt`? i think you are getting confused in the console. you might want to restart your R and write down your code in a script and run it sequentially. Right now, your claim is not reproducible

Comment: Yes, if you want a separate copy of a data table, you should use `data.table::copy`

Comment: It was a simple typo. As for why you can't reproduce it, I have no answer. The only thing I did to get it in the first place was: Foo<-as.data.table(Foodataframe) followed by Bar<-Foo and for some reason Foo worked but Bar didn't. My guess is there's an obscure glitch somewhere.